# Blocking and Unblocking SIGINT and SIGQUIT

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am writing a program that has two for loops and during the first for loop (just prints 1-5 and sleeps 1 second in between) SIGINT and SIGQUIT are to be blocked and in the second for loop only SIGINT is to be blocked. I successfully block the correct signals for the first for loop, then on the second for loop, I try to remove SIGQUIT from being blocked but both signals still seem to be blocked.

Here is what I have as of right now:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>


void hd1(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGINT){
        printf(" SIGINT Recieved\n");
    }else if(sig == SIGQUIT){
        printf(" SIGQUIT Recieved\n");
    }
}


int main(){
    sigset_t new_set;
    sigset_t old_set;

    //struct sigaction act;
    //memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));

    //act.sa_handler = hd1;

    //sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0);
    //sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0);

    sigemptyset(&new_set);
    sigaddset(&new_set, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&new_set, SIGQUIT);

    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &new_set, &old_set);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }


    sigdelset(&new_set, SIGQUIT);


    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I have tried using `sigprocmask` to unblock and setmask to reset the mask but it terminates the program after the loop when I unblock the signal.

Comment: have you tries `sigemptyset(....);siggaddset( ..., SIGINT);sigprocmask( SIG_UNBLOCK, ... );` ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`sigprocmask();`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) a second time. And use `SIG_SETMASK`

> SIG_SETMASK
>   The set of blocked signals is set to the argument set.

```
sigdelset(&new_set, SIGQUIT);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &new_set, NULL);
```

Comment: from man: SIG_BLOCK: The set of blocked signals is *the union* of the current set and the set argument.

Comment: I tried using sigprocmask (SIG_SETMASK, ...) and SIG_UNBLOCK and SIG_BLOCK, and im still getting the same result

Comment: @zsloan112 did you understand that you need two **different** call of `sigprocmask()` ?

Comment: Yes, i put thd ze on

Comment: Sorry on mobile, cant delete that comment, but yes, I tried the second sigprocmask aftet the sigdelset